# ViewFlipper on swipe, animate to next page but refresh the current view with new content?

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, view, viewflipper

I am trying to make a small dynamic book on Android.

I currently have a viewFlipper and gesture detector to swipe between the different pages in the book. This works ok if it is a fixed number of pages to a book, but I want to make it dynamic and also memory efficient by saying:

-create a linear layout with a scrollview, put this into the view flipper
-load content to that view
-on page swipe, animate to next page view but refresh the linear layout and load page2 content..etc
-on page swipe to go back a page, refresh view and load that page numbers content..etc

is there a way of doing this? instead of creating a lot of pages and overloading the memory?

Comment: I don't see why not, depending on your animation you should only need to keep three views in memory at a time max, one back, one current, and one forward.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution would be to use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with your own custom [PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html). In the [OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) you would load the next piece of content and then call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.